# Ubuntu iso autorun issues

Tags: 10.04, installation, wubi, iso

I have just downloaded [Ubuntu 10.04](http://ubuntu.cs.utah.edu/releases/10.04/ubuntu-10.04.3-desktop-i386.iso). Once done, I mount the iso onto a virtual cd drive and attempt to run the cd and install Linux as a Windows application.

The problem is each time I mount the iso and doubleclick to start the cd, it just opens as folder. This happens even when I rightclick and select autorun.

**Can anyone suggest some help, please? I desperatelty need to get Ubuntu 10.04 installed.**

Answer (score 1):

Download the same release of `wubi.exe`, save it in the **same directory** as the ISO, then run wubi without mounting the ISO (it's not necessary). You can copy the `wubi.exe` off the ISO instead of downloading, but if you do download it make sure it's the same release... i.e. from the site you downloaded the ISO from - so it will be here: http://ubuntu.cs.utah.edu/releases/10.04/wubi.exe